# If (a,b)=1, prove that a, a+b, a+2b,...,a+nb has infinitely many composite numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Question is in title.

I've tried to plug in a few numbers to find a pattern, but I can't seem to find one.

Comment: What is $(a,b)=1$?

Comment: Greatest common divisor of a and b is 1. In other words, a and b are relatively prime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a \not= 1$ the numbers of the form $a + (ka)b$ are all composite.

If $a = 1$ the numbers of the form $1 + b^n$ are all composite for odd $n$.

Comment: I understand the a /= 1 scenario, but can you give a proof for the a=1 scenario?

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN $1+X^n$ is a polynomial that has $X=-1$ as a root ($n$ is odd!), hence, you can split off a linear factor $X+1$. Which means that $b+1\mid 1+b^n$

Comment: I am not sure if $a=0$ is excluded by the problem statement; for this your $a\ne1$ case does not work - but of course it implies $b=\pm1$ and ten  $0+nb$ is composite for composite $n$.

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN If $n\in\mathbb Z$, $n\ge 3$ is odd, then $$1+b^n=(1+b)\left(b^{n-1}-b^{n-2}+b^{n-3}-\cdots+b^0\right)$$